# CCMenu is causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, but I can't backtrace my code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, nszombies

I'm having `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` problems with `cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1`.

I have enabled `NSZombies`, hoping to see where in my code am I accessing an object I shouldn't be accessing.

The problem occurs in `CCMenu.m`, here:

```
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSAssert(state_ == kCCMenuStateTrackingTouch, @"[Menu ccTouchMoved] -- invalid state");

    CCMenuItem *currentItem = [self itemForTouch:touch];

    if (currentItem != selectedItem_) {
        [selectedItem_ unselected];   // <--- selectedItem_ is a zombie
        selectedItem_ = currentItem;
        [selectedItem_ selected];
    }
}
```

I can observe that `selectedItem_` is a zombie.

This is `CCMenu` code, not mine - I should be looking at my own code. So I take a look at the backtrace:

[image]

This doesn't really help me: The backtrace does not reach my own code. That's `cocos2d-iphone` code.

What should I do to address this error then?

Comment: For the curious, [I found the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19533400/555690) - but I'm still interested in knowing how to address this kind of problem, because this time I was just lucky.

Answer (score -1):

Omega, you should be careful with ownership:

```
if (currentItem != selectedItem_)
        selectedItem_ = currentItem; // is plain wrong on non ARC mode.
```

You should synthesize retained setter for selectedItem_

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) CCMenuItem* selectedItem;
```

...

```
@synthesize selectedItem;
```

Then using setter assignement. Not plain pointer assignment.

```
self.selectedItem_ = currentItem;
// is actually kind of
// [selectedItem_ autorelease]
// selectedItem_ = [currentItem retain]
```

Comment: your answer is incorrect. both selectedItem_ and currentItem are retained in an array when that routine executes. The only reason i can see for this is that @Omega removed the selectedItem_ as child of the CCMenu somehow, without overriding the 'removeChild' methods of CCMenu in order to set the assigned iVars to nil after removal from the array.

Comment: Yves, my solution is incorrect (i didn't see it was inside CCmenu). But the design of CCMenu still relies on ownership GUI. Yes, this is not what make the app actually crashing, but the consequence of client implementation. By the way you should admit that the usage of selectedItem_ relies on lot of GUI logic stuff. You said it, selectedItem_ as been popped of the child hierarchy, and that's what make selectedItem_ dangling. The fact is, SelectedItem_ should not be dangling, that should never happen. Even if the client of that code is not doing what is expected, that should not crash this way

Comment: By the way, great game this "Max Power Adventures" ;) . I'm a big fan

Comment: New one in the works ... old style, funny and will have a PVP capability. Regarding selectedItem_, i agree with your diagnostic. This is why i would subclass CCMenu to implement a menu that accepts 'vanishing' items : encapsulate the proper handling of such details, and protect the UI api client.