# What to do if the user is holding on a CCMenuItemImage, then the CCMenu removes it, and then he untaps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I found a problem with my `CCMenu` instances using `cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1`.

Create a `CCMenu` and give it a `CCMenuItemImage` instance. Put your finger on it.

Now, somehow, while still holding your finger on the button, make the `CCMenu` dispose of it. Like `removeAllChildren` or something. Could be a timed event, whatever.

Right now, the button you were tapping is gone.

Remove your finger from the screen.

This will give an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error in this `CCMenu` method:

```
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSAssert(state_ == kCCMenuStateTrackingTouch, @"[Menu ccTouchMoved] -- invalid state");

    CCMenuItem *currentItem = [self itemForTouch:touch];

    if (currentItem != selectedItem_) {
        [selectedItem_ unselected];
        selectedItem_ = currentItem;
        [selectedItem_ selected];
    }
}
```

Because `selectedItem_`, which I suppose was the button you were pressing, has been released. But since your finger was still pressing, and it moved, `CCMenu` attempts to access it.

What do I do here? My game does need to remove `CCMenuItemImage` instances on a pretty dynamic way, and there is always a chance that the player is pressing one of them. I must remove them, I can't say *"if he's pressing X button, do not remove it"*.

Comment: is removing necessary? would disabling and making invisible do?

Comment: @abhineetprasad: I'm afraid not. There are other solutions I'm now working on of course, but I'm interested in getting this one fixed.

Comment: are there selectors being called when CCMenuItemImage is selected?

Comment: @abhineetprasad: It does when you tap the button, yeah.

Comment: have you tried removing the entire ccmenu rather than just its children? Sounds like you need an extra safety check where the item's selector is performed on the target. If this is done inside the ccmenu rather than by items it should help to remove the menu. If not set a breakpoint and check if maybe the target is nil or a zombie and then take it from there, the solution will offer itself eventually if you know the exact cause of the crash. Enable exception breakpoint if you haven't already.